# Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories

Tags: asp.net, node.js, angular, asp.net-core

I am receiving the following error when I host my asp.net core on IIS.  Locally it works fine:

```
Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

InvalidOperationException: Failed to start Node process. To resolve this:.

[1] Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories. Current PATH enviroment variable is: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6;C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;S:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;S:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;S:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;; Make sure the Node executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause. Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
```

Can someone give me hint to fix it?

Comment: And do you have node.js installed? What happens when you run `node --version` in the command line?

Comment: I agree with @jakerella. Just as the error message that you received says, you either don't have node installed (https://nodejs.org/en/) or you don't have a PATH variable set up which points to it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After publishing the website to another port, it runs beautifully

Answer (score 0):

Add user npm path. Eg : C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm (Win 10).